# Remove element from vector.Vector

Tags: go

```
//Remove cl (*client) from clients (vector.Vector)
for i := 0; i < clients.Len(); i++ {
    if cl == clients.At(i).(*client) {
        clients.Delete(i)
        break
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter way to remove an element from a vector?

Comment: shorter than `clients.Delete(i)?`

Comment: @cthom06 I don't know the index of the element in the vector

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you asked for, but do not use Vector, use a slice instead, [see here for a summary of some slice-idioms and their (deprecated/discouraged) Vector equivalents](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/eh3gh/slice_support_and_containervector/).

You could do something like:

```
for i, c := range clients {
    if c == client {
         clients = append(clients[:i], clients[i+1:]...)
    }
}
```

And obviously it is trivial to define your own delete method for your own types which does the same.